# ORMLite --- After .commit , .setAutoCommit --- Connection NOT closed

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling, ormlite

I use ORMLite on a solution made by server and clients.

On server side I use PostgreSQL, on client side I use SQLite. In code, I use the same ORMLite methods, without taking care of the DB that is managed (Postgres or SQLite). I used also pooled connection.

I don't have connection opened, when I need a Sql query, ORMLite takes care to open and close the connection.

Sometime I use the following code to perform a long operation in background on server side, so in DB PostgreSql.

```
final ConnectionSource OGGETTO_ConnectionSource = ...... ;
final DatabaseConnection OGGETTO_DatabaseConnection =
     OGGETTO_ConnectionSource.getReadOnlyConnection( "tablename" ) ;
OGGETTO_DAO.setAutoCommit(OGGETTO_DatabaseConnection, false); 
// do long operation with Sql Queries ;
OGGETTO_DAO.commit(OGGETTO_DatabaseConnection);
OGGETTO_DAO.setAutoCommit(OGGETTO_DatabaseConnection, true);
```

I noted that the number of open connections increased, therefore after sometime the number is so big to stop the server (SqlException "too many clients connected to DB").
I discovered that it's due to the code snippet above, it seems that after this snippet the connection is not closed e remain open.
Of course I cannot add at the end a "OGGETTO_ConnectionSource.close()", because it closes the pooled connection source.
If I add at the end "OGGETTO_DatabaseConnection.close();", it doesn't work, open connections continue to increase.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I discovered that it's due to the code snippet above, it seems that after this snippet the connection is not closed e remain open.

Let's RTFM.  Here are the javadocs for the [`ConnectionSource.getReadOnlyConnection(...)` method](https://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/support/ConnectionSource.html#getReadOnlyConnection-java.lang.String-).  I will quote:

```
Return a database connection suitable for read-only operations. After you are done,
you should call releaseConnection(DatabaseConnection).
```

You need to do something like the following code:

```
DatabaseConnection connection = connectionSource.getReadOnlyConnection("tablename");
try {
   dao.setAutoCommit(connection false);
   try {
      // do long operation with Sql Queries
      ...
      dao.commit(connection);
   } finally {
      dao.setAutoCommit(connection, true);
   }
} finally {
   connectionSource.releaseConnection(connection);
}
```

BTW, this is approximately what the [`TransactionManager.callInTransaction(...)` method](https://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/misc/TransactionManager.html#callInTransaction-com.j256.ormlite.support.ConnectionSource-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) is doing although it has even more try/finally blocks to ensure that the connection's state is reset.  You should probably switch to it.  Here are the docs for [ORMLite database transactions](https://ormlite.com/docs/transactions).

Comment: First of all Thank you; I implemented this method based on your answer: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66356373/how-to-write-several-item-in-table-at-the-same-time-using-ormlite".  You wrote me: "If you just want to insert and update a large number of records with higher performance then you can disable auto-commit, do the operations, and then commit.". I'll try also with Transaction Manager, that I already used.

Comment: About Transaction Manager I experienced that it locks DB, and that is exactly what I need to avoid; otherwise during long background operations other threads cannot do activities on DB.

Comment: Makes sense @Fausto70.  I was thinking that it would be good for TransactionManager to support a auto-commit on/off wrapped Callable.

Comment: Hi again @Gray, do you mean that I can set TransactionManager so to have autocommit on/off (and in that case I don't know how to do it), or do you mean that it could be good to have this feature not existing today?

Comment: Sorry the feature doesn't exist but it would be a good idea to add it @Fausto70.